# How are phrases such as "How beautiful" usually analyzed?

Tags: english, determiners

In English (and I believe in other languages, though I'm not certain), question
words like "how" and "what" can be used as intensifiers, in phrases like

> How beautiful

or

> What splendor

or

> What a beautiful child

Now, I can image analyzing the first as some kind of adverb, and the second as some kind of determiner--at the very least, they both both seem to be the same kind of thing as in the corresponding question phrases:

> How big is she?

or

> What apple do you want?

But I'm absolutely lost as to how to analyze "What a beautiful child"--can anyone help me out?

Comment: I think the usual term is *exclamative adjective*, though perhaps *exclamativizer* would be more appropriate.

Comment: Yes other languages (at least ones related to English) have this. Spanish: *Que caballero!* "What a gentleman!" German: *Wie Schade.* "What a pity."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of literature that addresses the subject matter in the question directly. I have, however, thought about such cases quite a bit, and I have an unpublished paper that addresses some of the relevant data in part.

The interrogative word *how* is often a predependent of an adjective. It is asking for the relevant degree associated with the property expressed by the adjective, e.g. *how big*, *how loud*, *how helpful*, etc. These are relatively straightforward adjective phrases (APs), as pointed out in the question. I do not see anything mysterious or unusual about them.

Concerning examples with *what*, I think *what* often functions basically just like *which*, e.g. *What apple do you have?* = *Which apple do you have?*, *What ideas is he promoting?* = *Which ideas is he promoting?* In these examples, both *what* and *which* are functioning as interrogative determiners. On an NP analysis of noun phrases, they are predependents of the nouns that they introduce.

But the analysis of examples like *what a beautiful child* are indeed more challenging. They are challenging because it appears as though the noun *child* takes two determiners, *what* and *a*. This seems to be a particular idiosyncracy of *what*. Other interrogative determiners are incapable of doing the same, e.g. **Which a beautiful child*.

However, English has a construction that seems related, e.g.

```
 how big (of) a fool

 too crazy (of) a man

 that bold (of) a move
```

In these cases, the preposition *of* appears optionally. With *what*, the preposition *of* cannot appear, e.g. **what of a beautiful child*. Furthermore, the indefinite article is obligatory in such cases. With *what*, the indefinite article need not appear, e.g.

```
 what beautiful children

            vs.

 *how big (of) fools

 *too crazy (of) men

 *that bold (of) the move
```

These examples further illustrate that the ability of *what* to appear in NPs such as *what a beautiful child* is an idiosyncracy of *what*. One analysis of the construction might view *what* as a nominal that takes an indefinite NP as its complement: *[what [a beautiful child]]*.

Finally, the following data can be construed as involving a type of ellipsis:

```
 How crazy (she is)!

 What a beautiful child (she is)!

 What fun (that was)!

 How entertaining (that is)!
```

The ellipsis mechanism optionally elides a definite pronoun and a form of the copula. This mechanism shows up in other constructions, e.g. *If (you are) interested, you should contact me*. I call this ellipsis mechanism *slicing*. I will share my unpublished manuscript on slicing if anyone is interested. I can be contacted via my email; my address is on my Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Tjo3ya.

Comment: Hi Tim. I'd be interested in seeing your manuscript, if you wouldn't mind sending it along (my email add. is on my profile page). I like 'slicing' - very Ross-esque.

Comment: @P Elliott, thanks for your interest. I just sent the manuscript to the email address on your bio page. I see you have worked on island repair. Concerning any feedback you might have on the manuscript, I'd certainly like to see it.